# How to automatically update files from SharePoint Designer?

Tags: sharepoint-online, synchronisation, sitepages

I develop a SharePoint solution and I need to update files everytime.

I find a solution for the files in the Site Assets library. I go on the library (or the list), I click on the ribbon, "Library" tab and "Synch" to synchronize the folder on my desktop :

[image: sync]

After that, I can open the file in my favorite editor and when I save, the file is updated on the SharePoint Online.

The issue is, I can't do the same thing for the Site Pages library.

[image: impossible_sync]

Any suggestions or reasons ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not everything can be synchronized, Site Pages and even the Pages library cannot be synched, presumably because the file system might not know how to deal with these specialized libraries.

Comment: Ok, so I'll update files manually.
Thank you for your answer !

Answer (score 0):

I find the answer: on the file from the SharePoint Designer interface, right click and "Open with".
You just have to browse your favorite text editor exe.

[image]

Comment: I do not see how this is the answer to how you sync the files offline?

Comment: Read my first post, the issue was that "After that, I can open the file in my favorite editor and when I save, the file is updated on the SharePoint Online."

Comment: I'll recommend change the title of your post to clarify the real issue. "How to synchronize Site Pages library from SharePoint Online?" is not very accurate

Comment: Ok, do you think it is better now ?